# What was the average height of men and women in pre-Roman Gaul?

Tags: ancient-rome, anthropology

I was having a discussion with my friend on how much taller Celts and Germanics were to Romans and it dawned on me that we had no idea how tall Celts actually were. I'm referring to the period when Rome was expanding and trying to conquer Europe.

I'm not a historian. I tried searching on the Internet, but different websites give different answers. Many websites say that Celts were close to 6 feet tall on average compared to 5'6" Romans, but that sounds too crazy even for me! I couldn't find any actual legit sources on these topics!

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: I'm not a historian. I try searching on the Internet, but different websites give different answers. Many websites say that Celts were close to 6 feet tall on average compared to 5'6" Romans, but that sounds too crazy even for me! I couldn't find any actual legit sources on these topics!

Comment: How could we possibly know? Measuring bones from excavated burial sites may give a rough idea, but there were no official statistics in those days! Also, the term 'Romans' could include people  of different ethnic origins from all over the empire.

Comment: You'd likely have to look for such information in French as most archaeology on the Gauls comes from France. If there is a compendium on grave finds from across the Celtic world I'd be interested in seeing such myself. Given the large range that Celtic settlements existed over plus the timescales involved there's not going to be a fixed height just like there's not a fixed height for modern Europeans but there are regional averages.

Comment: You will probably be interested in this question: [What was the average height of Roman men and women?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17072/what-was-the-average-height-of-roman-men-and-women).

Comment: This will probably interest you as well. This says during the Roman occupation of Britain, the average English person got TALLER, suggesting the Romans were taller, but this could also possibly be explained by better nourishment. I'm sure there are other possible explanations too. [Highs and lows of an Englishman's average height over 2,000 years](https://www.ox.ac.uk/news/2017-04-18-highs-and-lows-englishman%E2%80%99s-average-height-over-2000-years-0).

Comment: Lastly, this will explain the last piece: [Height and health in Roman and Post-Roman Gaul, a life course approach](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1879981721000796). Just search that document (search by holding the Ctrl button down while you press the "f" key) for the word "height", it's mentioned 8 times. It explains that Roman height was in decline during the time that, though again, why is undetermined. Disappointingly, they do not give a height, but they do reference a TON of research that DOES go into specific heights.

Comment: You may want to watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noUYQvsNTJU